# Objective C tip?

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, nsarray, setter, instance-variables

I want to replace this:

```
self.fajerImage     = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FirstViewBG_5N.png"];
self.shrogImage     = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FirstViewBG_4N.png"];
self.dohorImage     = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FirstViewBG_3N.png"];
self.aaserImage     = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FirstViewBG_2N.png"];
self.mgribImage     = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FirstViewBG_1N.png"];
self.eeshaImage     = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FirstViewBG_0N.png"];
```

With a for loop.. I don't know how to call the ivars one after another in a loop..

Please note that putting them in an array before the loop is a great idea that I have not been successful in implementing..

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that initial wrong answer -- The actual way to do this is with key value coding. See my answer for a guide, and example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One great way to do this involves [key value coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), as discussed in [this blog post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/5-key-value-coding-approaches-in-cocoa.html). Try using:

```
NSArray *nameArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"fajerImage",
                                                     @"shrogImage",
                                                     @"dohorImage",
                                                     @"aaserImage",
                                                     @"mgribImage",
                                                     @"eeshaImage",
                                                     nil];

int i = 0;
for (NSString *name in nameArray) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"FirstViewBG_%dN.png", i++]];
    [self setValue:image forKey:name];
}

[nameArray release];
```

(You should replace `UIImage` in my code above with the actual object type, if I've gotten it wrong.)

Comment: This won't modify the original image variables, as `name` is just a pointer local to the loop that will get changed to a completely different `UIImage`. Instead, you need some way to have pointers to the original instance variables.

Comment: Just changed my answer to something a bit more respectable. Sorry about that, it was definitely wrong, initially.

Comment: Yikes, can you tell I've been leaning on xcode a bit too much?

Comment: there, fixed, and cleaned up where `i` gets incremented.

Comment: AND you deleted a necessary square bracket :).. Thanks!

Comment: Shaved 100 lines of code thanks to your tip and some renaming, cheers! xD

Answer (score 3):

You could use Key Value Coding syntax:

```
NSString *names=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"eeshaImage",@"mgribImage",@"aaserImage",@"dohorImage",...,nil];

for (int i=0; i<names.count; i++) {
      NSString *name=[names objectAtIndex:i];
      UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"FirstViewBG_%dN.png",i
      [self setValue:image forKey:name];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

A coworker of mine is fond of a pattern like the following (untested):

```
 id *images[] = {
    &eeshaImage,
    &mgribImage,
    &aaserImage,
    &dohorImage,
    &shrogImage,
    &fajerImage
 };

 for (size_t i = 0;i < sizeof(images) / sizeof(*images);++i) {
    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"FirstViewBG_%zuN.png", i];
    *(images[i]) = [[UIImage imageNamed:name] retain];
 }
```

You have to ask yourself if the cost in readability is worth it just to make it a tiny bit more extensible, though.

Comment: yeesh... i would recommend *agains* using this, since this ends up as direct ivar access, which bypasses the setter methods (which may be triggering some KVO methods or custom code)

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can do that is usually fast enough is allocate your images on demand rather than try and initialize them all at once.  Name them something like "FirstViewBG_Fajer.png" and then write an instance method like:

```
- (UIImage *) imageNamed:(NSString *) name {
    return [UIImage imageNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat:
    @"FirstViewBG_%@.png", name]];
}
```